# Finding the partial sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I'm to find the sum of the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty(\sqrt{n(n+1)} - \sqrt{n(n-1)} - 1) $$
And I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Infinity is `\infty`

Comment: @GarethMa Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Prove that the partial sum is

$$\sum_{n=0}^N (\sqrt{n(n + 1)} - \sqrt{n(n - 1)} - 1) = \sqrt{N(N + 1)} - (N + 1)$$

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: @Ghost https://www.amazon.com/MaxUSee-Telescope-400x40mm-Portable-Beginners/dp/B071J5GBWY?language=en_US This might help

Comment: Nvm, I got it already. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Ghost do you mind accepting the answer if it helped? (btw my reply is referring to telescope -> telescoping series :)

Answer (score 0):

Want
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\sqrt{n(n+1)} - \sqrt{n(n-1)} - 1)
$.

Tuens out that it telescopes quite nicely and the partial sums can be
explicitly evaluated.

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=0}^m(\sqrt{n(n+1)} - \sqrt{n(n-1)} - 1)\\
&=-1+\sum_{n=1}^m(\sqrt{n(n+1)} - \sqrt{n(n-1)} - 1)\\
&=-1+\sum_{n=1}^m\sqrt{n(n+1)} - \sum_{n=1}^m\sqrt{n(n-1)} - \sum_{n=1}^m 1\\
&=-1+\sum_{n=1}^m\sqrt{n(n+1)} - \sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\sqrt{n(n+1)} - m\\
&=-1-m+\sqrt{m(m+1)}\\
&=\sqrt{m(m+1)}-(m+1)\\
&=(\sqrt{m(m+1)}-(m+1))\dfrac{\sqrt{m(m+1)}+(m+1)}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}+(m+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{m(m+1)-(m+1)^2}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}+(m+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{-m-1}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}+(m+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{m/(m+1)}+1}\\
&\to -\frac12
\qquad\text{as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$